# detecting aggregate root at domain driven design, considering existing old db

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, cqrs, ddd-repositories

doing an exercise about ddd and modernizing an old asp.net app
, and having difficulty deciding about an aggregate root
i have an old db that employees are reporting there work hours to

most common use case is employee report a whole month of work in single post (n **work report** rows)

1. a work report row in database represent a single work day in a month
2. an employee may have zero or many work report rows for a given day.

my first idea was to make work report as the root since it's relations in db puts it in the middle,
but since the user(employee) gets and inputs an array of work reports
i'm not sure if it fits the pattern by handling array of work reports in one unit of work.
so i guess my question is what can be the aggregate root in my scenario
attaching the db erd for the specific problem.
[Work Report diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bLvT.png)

appreciate any thoughts or ideas about modeling it correctly.
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> appreciate any thoughts or ideas about modeling it correctly. thanks,

If what you have is a *database*, in other words, if you are just capturing information from the outside world and caching it for later use, then putting a *domain model* in front of that database is probably overkill.

The point at which domain models start to become interesting is when you are combining new information (from the outside world) with old information (what you've already written into the database).  In other words, the domain model isn't about information capture so much as it is about exercising domain protocols.

If that's not what you are doing, then finding a sensible "aggregate" is going to be really difficult.

Comment: Thanks, the db I'm working on represent more than just the work hour report. ( Has an employee model,finance model and more)My goal eventually is to be able thru time to move from the old app to a newer one. That's why i started with ddd, based on my existing db.